# How to display a one-to-many relation in Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to display the one to many relations just like other Dynamics CRM standard's one to many relations  (e.g.: incident to faxes or accounts to tasks) which are presented in a table based form (see the Accounts > Common > Activities) rather than in look up fields.
I'm using the `CreateOneToMany` request method.

Thanks,

Comment: why are you doing is programmatically?

Comment: yes, it is programmatically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution in a MSDN forum.
Hopefully it will help somebody else:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/087fb008-9a3d-43d4-b191-6d776a96e535

Thanks,

Javier Andres Caceres Alvis

Microsoft C# MVP

Intel Black Belt Software Developer